# Convert a html checkbox input field to rails erb

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to convert this input field to ERB for my rails app:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="yesno" name="my-checkbox" data-on-text="YES" data-off-text="NO">
```

Above generates the following html:

```
   <div class="col-sm-10 question">
    <input name="my-checkbox" type="hidden" value="0" /><input class="yesno" name="my-checkbox" data-on-text="YES" data-off-text="NO" type="checkbox" value="1" id="assessment_answer_content" />
</div>
```

---

Here's what I'm using for ERB:

```
<%= builder.check_box :content, :class=>"yesno", :name=>"my-checkbox", :'data-on-text'=>"YES", :'data-off-text'=>"NO" %>
```

Generates identical HTML.

But when I use the erb code, I get a weird output (2 checkbox fields instead of one, see below). Where am I messing up?
[image]

Comment: What HTML does it generate?

Comment: Try this `<%= builder.check_box :content, :class=>"yesno", :name=>"my-checkbox", :data => {:on-text =>"YES", :off-text =>"NO"} %>`

Comment: @jordan see OP edits to show HTML output for both versions.

Comment: @test same result :(

Comment: Remove name parameter and then try